# display per class precision and per class recall for "pascal_voc_instance_segmentation_metrics"

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I trained Mask-RCNN with tensorflow object detection API on my custom dataset, I can run the evaluation script with the following command:

```
python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
    --pipeline_config_path ${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir ${MODEL_DIR} \
    --checkpoint_dir ${MODEL_DIR} \
    --eval_timeout 10
```

and my eval_configue looks as follows:

```
eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "pascal_voc_instance_segmentation_metrics"
  eval_instance_masks: true
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1
  include_metrics_per_category: false
  num_visualizations: 20
  visualization_export_dir: "/mypath"
}
```

using the commands and configue above I can get the

```
'PerformanceByCategory/AP@{}IOU/{}'
```

**what i want to do:**
I want to get  the

```
PerformanceByCategory/Precision@{}IOU/{}
PerformanceByCategory/Recall@{}IOU/{}
```

described in the eval folder [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f8dbd5f1f247102a4bf0412d088d7bb3e71ac6b0/research/object_detection/utils/object_detection_evaluation.py#L401)

it seems that the values:

```
precisions_per_class
recalls_per_class
```

are calculated in the [evaluate](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f8dbd5f1f247102a4bf0412d088d7bb3e71ac6b0/research/object_detection/utils/object_detection_evaluation.py#L1439) method and passed to another method "also called evaluate" [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f8dbd5f1f247102a4bf0412d088d7bb3e71ac6b0/research/object_detection/utils/object_detection_evaluation.py#L401) where it can only be displayed if the value

```
evaluate_precision_recall
```

[here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/object_detection_evaluation.py#L223) is set to True.

**what i tried:** i tried setting the value:evaluate_precision_recall to True by default in the class constructor which should display it but that didn't work.